# React-Native: Passing keyword in props for searching

Tags: react-native, react-props

I need a little help in a small issue. In my first screen, I have a flatlist which has some keywords. I want if I click on any keyword, I should be navigated to another screen with the prop  of that keyword. I am doing like this inside the flatlist:

```
<FlatList
    data={myRecentSearches}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
         onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("search", { searchValue: `${item.keyword}` })}>
          <Text>{item.keyword}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

In the next screen, I want the input field should already be initialized with that keyword.

```
const SearchScreen = (props) => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  return (
    <View activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <TextInput
          allowFontScaling={false}
          value={searchValue} //I want this value to be already initialized/populated with the prop
          returnKeyType="search"
          autoFocus
          />
      </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first screen have the SearchScreen like this:

```
return(
<SearchScreen keyWord={item.keyword}/>
)
```

And inside SearchScreen:

```
const SearchScreen = (props) => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(props.keyWord);
  return (
    <View activeOpacity={0.5} style={styles.searchContainer}>
        <TextInput
          allowFontScaling={false}
          value={searchValue} //I want this value to be already initialized/populated with the prop
          returnKeyType="search"
          autoFocus
          />
      </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: How can I have a search component like that in the first screen?

Comment: And what do you mean by <SearchComponent>?

Comment: One last thing ma'am, where shall I have to place return(<SearchScreen keyWord={item.keyword}/>) in the flatlist of first screen, in onPress function? will be grateful for this help :)

Comment: no no,inside return where you place your other div's for example:
`...rest of your code...
return(
<div>
...here other things you display..
<SearchScreen keyWord={item.keyword}/>
</div>
)`